# Prove that $|(A × B) × C| = |(C × B) × A|$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I need to prove that $|(A × B) × C| =   |(C × B) × A|$. I know that I must give a bijection between $|(A × B) × C|$ and   $|(C × B) × A|$ but I can't seem to find it. The functions I've found are not surjective.

Thanks.

Comment: I find it very hard to give a hint to this without spilling out the answer. What functions did you try? Maybe you did a mistake somewhere and one of them works. Also note that you need to treat the case where any of the sets is empty separately.

Comment: My function was the same as the one ploosu2 proposed. I think my proof for surjectivity and injectivity is not ok. I will do it again.

Comment: I suggest you post your work, it will benefit everyone.

Comment: Ok, so for injectivity:   let $f((x_1,y_1)z_1) = f((x_2,y_2)z_2)$,  then $((z_1,y_1),x_1) = ((z_2,y_2),x_2)$, so $x_1 = x_2$, $y_1 = y_2$ and $z_1 = z_2$.                              For surjectivity:     let $((z,y),x) \in (C×B)×A$ , so $z \in C, y \in B$ and $ x \in A$. This implies that $((x,y),z) \in (A × B) × C$. By definition of $f$, $f((x,y),z) = ((z,y),x)$, so $f$ is surjective. Is this correct?

Comment: [Edit](http://math.stackexchange.com/posts/773455/edit) it into the question, please.

Comment: It is correct.${}$

Comment: Is it really necessary to treat the case where any of the sets is empty? If so, why?

Comment: Say $C=\varnothing$. What is $f((x_1, y_1),z_1)$? What is $z_1$?

Answer (score 1):

How about: $f((a, b), c) = ((c, b), a)$?